# ON DUPLICATE update nothing

Tags: mysql

I know that I can use `UPDATE IGNORE` to pass on whether there is a duplicate key. How would I use the following syntax to do the same?

```
INSERT INTO table ON DUPLICATE KEY *do nothing*
```

Comment: Could try adding superfluous logic akin to `ON DUPLICATE KEY 1 = 1`

Comment: @MikePurcell Well by doing that you are doing "something". The question is to avoid doing anything.

Comment: `insert ignore` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it the exact same way.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table ....
```

That will silently skip any constraint violations. For a bulk insert (eg `insert ignore into table select ... from ...`), this will skip the rows that violate a constraint, but continue to insert all rows that can be.

Useful for duplicate removal.

Comment: Note, INSERT IGNORE also ignores other errors such as partitioning allocation errors and does not only ignore key conflicts.